# Replace values in range Rapidminer

Tags: replace, range, rapidminer

I am using Rapidminer Studio 6 and I want to replace values in dataset (or results, or series), lets say we have an attribute with values between 1 and 10, so I want to apply an operator which will replace values 1 to 4 and 8 to 10 by 0 so the new values will be 0's and numbers from 4 to 8. Say we have
2 4 1 5 7 9 -op-> 0 4 0 5 7 0.
Can someone tell me which operator to use, or subprocess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(copied from original answer)

You can use the `Generate Attributes` operator for this with `if` in the parameters section.

If your attribute is called `a2` and you want to change it to zero if its value is below 3 and above 5, the parameters to the `Generate Attributes` operator would look like this.

`attribute name: a2`

`function expressions: if(a2<3,0,if(a2>5,0,a2))`